# How to install a custom validator as part of an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I would like for a given eclipse plugin to install a custom validator. This validator would be the same one from [any file]->right click->Validate. Is this even possible? I cannot seem to find any helpful resources as "validation" just gets me all kinds of random google results relating to Eclipse RCP.